# Updating column value based on condition with substring

Tags: sql, spring-boot, liquibase

I need to change all values of a column that contain `autor` substring to `author`.

Example: My current row is `role-autor` and this needs to become `role-author`

Is it possible in liquibase?

Comment: Watch out for autorepeat, autorun etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<update tableName="your_table_name">
    <column name="role-autor" type="varchar(64)" valueComputed="REPLACE(role-autor, 'autor', 'author')" />
    <where>role-autor LIKE '%autor%'</where>
</update>
```

Please do the research of the StackOverflow blog there are some examples that can help you...

You will need to put it in the changeset tag :

```
<changeSet author="wiki" id="1.0.0-1">
    <update tableName="your_table_name">
        <column name="role-autor" type="varchar(64)" valueComputed="REPLACE(role-autor, 'autor', 'author')" />
        <where>role-autor LIKE '%autor%'</where>
    </update>
</changeset>
```

Something to read for more details about the changeset tag: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/changeset.html

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want `replace()`?

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, 'autor', 'author')
    where col like '%autor%';
```

Comment: yeah, just wanted to use the liquibase xml stuff